Does nature maximize or minimize spacetime curvature?
This question is based on the Einstein-Hilbert action, which states $$S=\frac{1}{2\kappa}\int_{ }^{ }R\sqrt{-g}d^{4}x,$$ where $R$, the Ricci Scalar, is some measure of the spacetime curvature.
The principle of stationary action states that the action can take on any extremal value, be it
a maximum, minimum, or saddle point. However, this is not always the case.
Take for example the action of a free-falling particle, which is the proper time between its start and end point.
This value is ALWAYS maximized, and is thus a special case of the principle of stationary action.
What I'm asking is, is there a similar flavor for gravity?
Is the total curvature of spacetime always minimized, maximized, or can it be either depending on the situation?

You should keep in mind that $R$ is not the "total" curvature. Curvature is a tensor, and in Lorentzian signature there isn't really a way to calculate a scalar magnitude.

The proper time is maximized because time has the opposite sign as space in the metric. Its absolute value is minimized.

I can't think of a way to explicitly construct this, so I'm going to leave it as a comment instead of an answer, but I believe it will generically be a saddle point (which is typical). Consider just the vacuum equations $R=0$, and the on-shell solution of Minkowski space. I think it should be possible to deform Minkowski space by modifying the metric so $R>0$ in some region and $R=0$ elsewhere (eg, in 2 spatial dimensions, add a hemispherical "bump" to the flat plane), and it should also be possible to do a deformation so $R<0$ in some region and $R=0$ elsewhere (less clear on this).

@paulina The proper time is maximized because that's what the geodesic equation implies, also, if it were minimized, everything would just travel at the speed of light.

@Javier well yes, but I was simply stating that the integral of $R$ over spacetime represents some kind of measure of the "total curvature".

That's fair, as long as you don't forget that there are plenty of curved spaces with $R=0$. Just wanted to point it out, just in case.

The variation principle of the EH-action gives the field equations $R_{\mu\nu}-1/2Rg_{\mu\nu}=0$ for the metric $g$. So $R(g)=\frac{2}{d} g^{\mu\nu}R_{\mu\nu}$, where $d=g^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\nu}$ is the number of spacetime dimensions. This equation for the scalar curvature is simply its definition as a contraction of the Ricci tensor times two. So we get $R=\frac{2}{d} R$. The only solution in $d\neq 2$ is $R(g)=0$. The case $d=2$ is special see string theory or Liouville gravity. Be aware however, that $R=0$ is not only the boring Euclidean or Minkowski spacetime. There are also much more complicated Ricci-flat manifolds like for example Calabi-Yau manifolds and the K3 surface.
If you have to your gravity coupled some matter fields or a non-zero dark energy then you get $R-\frac{d}{2}R+d\lambda=\kappa T$, where $T$ is the trace of your stress-energy tensor.
If you weant to view the EH-action as a gauge theory then its invariance under diffeomorphisms ahs the consequence that all solutions, which are related by conformal transformations describe the same physical solution. The space of all solutions is thus an orbit space of the diffeomorphism group of your space-time $X$. And the physical space is $Met(X)/Diff(X)$. Actually this can be refined to a moduli-stack but I digress.
Last thing: You can also consider manifolds with boundary, then you need to include the Gibbons-Hawking boundary term and then you have to consider also the extrinsic curvatur $K$ as an additional variable.

Thank you for your answer, but for clarity's sake could you please directly address the question?
For some it may be obvious what the implications of what you've outlined are, but for others who are less experienced it might be helpful to spell out the conclusion.
It's not clear what either part says about being minima or maxima (or saddle points) of the EH-action, in fact neither mention it.

As discussed in the other answer, most solutions to the vacuum Einstein field equations have vanishing Ricci scalar. However, it is also known that FRW manifold solutions can have a positive or negative Ricci scalar everywhere. These manifolds can be generated by continuously deforming away from flat Minkowski space. Therefore, the zero case is not a minimum of the Einstein-Hilbert action but rather a saddle point, although in some sense, $R=0$ is indeed the "least curvature" that you can hope for since it is the curvature of flat space.

The curvature of a volume of spacetime is equal to the amount of mass in that volume.
Gravitation maximizes local curvature by causing mass to be more dense. The limit is a black hole.
But "nature"  doesn't change the global curvature of the universe at all, which is equivalent to its (constant) mass.
